# if statement for a model on a different show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, rails-api

I have two tables

```
create_table "book_rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "room"
  t.string   "room_number"
end
```

and

```
create_table "rooms", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "room_number"
end
```

in the rooms show page i want to display 'book_rooms.room_number' with same value with 'rooms.room_number' but I keep getting all book room objects printed out as an array in every room show page

rooms show page

```
<% @customer = BookRoom.all %>
<% if @customer[0].room_number = @room.room_number %>   
  <% @customer.each do |c| %>
    <%= c.first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

pls is there something I am not doing right? the if statement is meant to be false if the room_numbers dont tally but they still get printed out regardless! i am stuck

Answer (score 2):

```
BookRoom.where(:room_number => @room.room_number)
```

This will fetch all the `BookRoom` with **room_number** from a specific `Room` (which is `@room`). 
By the way I guess your association is not correct. There must be a `has_many` relation between `BookRoom` and `Room`.

The problem you're facing is, in your `@customer` variable you assign all `BookRooms`. Then based on this variable you created a loop. THus all the `BookRoom` are displaying.

Also, in your `book_rooms` schema there is no `first_name`.

**EDIT**

**BUG:** In your if condition you used the `=` operator instead of `==`

```
<% @customer = BookRoom.all %>
<% @customer.each do |c| %>
  <% if c.room_number == @room.room_number %>   
    <%= c.first_name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also, you should be defining the ActiveRecord relation by the id. Not sure why room_number is a string but if you have defined your object as a typical rails migration, it should have generated an id column by default.

Comment: bare with me.. theres actually a first_name column just didnt include it. erm book_room already belongs_to a parent so I didnt associate both models.. so theres no way I can implement my logic without them associated with each other? because I already tried '.where' and it does the same thing... and so the if statement doesnt stop the loop?

Comment: @ChineduLloydAbalogu, Edited answer.